# Parse json in sharepoint 2010 webpart

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, sharepoint-2010, asp.net-ajax

So I do in php

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'parser.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: 'Data=' + $.toJSON(schedule),
         success: function (res) {
                  alert(res);
         }
       });
```

Object that comes to shedule

```
stdClass object {
   weeks => array (1) (
     [0] => stdClass object {
       0 => stdClass object {}
       1 => stdClass object {}
       2 => stdClass object {}
       3 => stdClass object {}
       4 => stdClass object {}
       5 => stdClass object {}
       6 => stdClass object {}
       alltime => (int) 60
     }
   )
   alltime => (int) 60
   hours => (int) 60
}
```

How to pass an ajax request to sharepoint 2010?
And then on the server to parse. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to call a REST service in the server-side code (C#/VB) in a SharePoint 2010 Web Part?

Comment: I am interested in how this is done on shrepoint 2010 (C #)

Comment: I am bad understand english. sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is extremely easy to do with .NET 4.0. From [The Rise Of JSON](http://visitmix.com/writings/the-rise-of-json):

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
dynamic result = JsonValue.Parse(webClient.DownloadString(
    "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?oauth_token=XXXXXXX"));
Console.WriteLine(result.response.user.firstName);
```

Unfortunately SharePoint 2010 is built on top of .NET 3.5 so we can't use that code.

Instead, to call a web service we can use something like the code described in [Getting data from a REST service](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/02/15/getting-data-from-a-rest-service-using-c.aspx) using C#:

```
public string GetMessage( string endPoint )
{
    HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest( endPoint );

    using ( var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse( ) )
    {
        var responseValue = string.Empty;

        if ( response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK )
        {
            string message = String.Format( "POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", 
                response.StatusCode );
            throw new ApplicationException( message );
        }

        // grab the response
        using ( var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream() )
        {
            using ( var reader = new StreamReader( responseStream ) )
            {
                responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return responseValue;
    }
}
```

Then we can use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to parse to JSON response.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.DeserializeObject(response);
```

The JavaScriptSerializer is a little quirky to work with. If you want something a little more elegant you can use a third-party library like [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to parse the JSON reponse.

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(responseValue);
```

I hope this helps,